# How to find out Intersection of a time range with the given set of time ranges in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, gridview

I have a GridView, Which has three columns Name, Start Date and End Date.
Time Ranges are in sorted order. Means GridView is sorted by Start Date by default.
User wants to insert a new Row with Name, Start Date and End Date.
If time Span between new Start Date and new End Date intersects with any other(could be more than one Row) time spans of other rows. Those row will be deleted and this new Record will be inserted in GridView. If there is no intersection with any of the time span then simply it will be added to the GridView.

If have written the following code to find out intersection between two Dates (datatype is DateTime).

```
    public class DateTimeRange
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }

    public bool Intersects(DateTimeRange test)
    {
        if (this.Start > this.End || test.Start > test.End)
            return false;
            //throw new InvalidDateRangeException();

        if (this.Start == this.End || test.Start == test.End)
            return false; // No actual date range

        if (this.Start == test.Start || this.End == test.End)
            return true; // If any set is the same time, then by default there must be some overlap. 

        if (this.Start < test.Start)
        {
            if (this.End > test.Start && this.End < test.End)
                return true; // Condition 1

            if (this.End > test.End)
                return true; // Condition 3
        }
        else
        {
            if (test.End > this.Start && test.End < this.End)
                return true; // Condition 2

            if (test.End > this.End)
                return true; // Condition 4
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

So I am planning to iterate the GridView row wise(one by one), store the index of Rows which are intersecting with  new recode. and after iteration I will delete rows of these indexes and insert new Recode. 
So my Doubt is there any better way to do this in less complexity or in easier way.

Precondition: All time ranges are mutually exclusive initially, means there is no intersection among rows.

Comment: What is your question? if you are asking about your code, I'm not sure if it will work, I am sure you can write same logic with fewer if-else blocks. use nested if blocks , use <= and >= operators, that should help reduce the complexity. Also , think about unit testing this method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two sets a and b do not intersect in these cases:

```
---|<--A-->|----------------
-------------|<--B-->|------

a.End < b.Start

--------------|<--A-->|-----
---|<--B-->|----------------

a.Start > b.End
```

So if you combine the two cases you get:

```
a.End < b.Start || a.Start > b.End
```

Now you can negate it:

```
!(a.End < b.Start || a.Start > b.End)
```

To optimize, using De Morgan you obtain:

```
a.End >= b.Start && a.Start <= b.End
```

This last condition tells you that they `not` do `don't intersect` (double negation).
So they intersect.

Border conditions are excluded. Replace `<`/`>` with `<=`/`>=` and vice versa to have it the other way around.

Comment: Also , do not allow construction of illegal range objects, make sure there is only one creation method, and in it both start time and end time should be defined and end time should be larger than start time

Comment: Really nice explanation! Shows the logic and the code at once :)

Comment: Well explained,  how to apply this logic for a set of time ranges effectively?

Comment: if you have n ranges from r1 to rn then you need to compare each one with all the others, so you'll have to compare (n^2)/2. probably there's a theorem that reduces that number to n*ln(n) but I wouldn't waste time on that unless you need 1000+ comparisons per second...

Comment: As I think about it, if the ranges are ordered by start date you can probably compare them all in even less time, approximating n, because there's an algorithm based on *cursors*, but it's really not needed for small batches...